# Find remainder when $f(x^{12})$ is divided by $f(x)$

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

What will be the remainder when $f(x^{12})$ is divided by $f(x)$ where : $$f(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x +1$$

I have already tried but found no idea how I can do this question.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with division algebras? Please take a look at the [tag excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/division-algebras/info) before using a tag you are not familiar with. Leaving the algebraic-number-theory tag as I can see this emerging on a course on ANT.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Actually I didn't knew what all tags I should give and I found the name related to my question so I gave that tag too.

Comment: $f(x) = x^5 + x^4 + ... + 1 = (x^6 - 1)/(x-1)$.  $f(x^{12}) = (x^{72} - 1)/(x^{12} - 1)$  That might help.  Or it might not.

Comment: I too gave it a try... But how to take it to the answer? @fleablood

Comment: Since $f(x)$ divides $x^6-1$, you can first reduce mod $x^6-1$, and then reduce mod $f(x)$.

Comment: Almost the same idea as @stewbasic, but using modulo $f$ directly: as $x^6=1+(x-1)f$, you have $x^6\equiv 1 \mod f$, then $x^{12}\equiv 1 \mod f$, $f(x^{12})\equiv f(1)=6 \mod f$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x^{12}) - 6 &= (x^{60}-1) + (x^{48}-1) + (x^{36}-1) + (x^{24}-1)+(x^{12}-1)
\end{align*}
Note that $x^{mk}-1 $ is divisible by $x^k-1$. Thus all terms on the right side are divisible by $x^6-1$ and hence by $f(x)$. Thus the remainder is 6.

Comment: Since the remainder is constant, your answer should work for all $x$ but if we put $x=1,0$ then the remainder from division of both the functions comes out to be zero. Am I messing up something?

Comment: What we have is $f(x^{12}) = f(x)Q(x) + 6$ for some polynomial $Q(x)$. When $x= 1$, $f(x^{12}) = 6, f(x) = 6$ but $Q(x) = 0$. When $x=0$, $f(x^{12}) = 1, f(x) = 1$, but $Q(x) = -5$. Remainder $r(x)$ when a polynomial $q(x)$  divides another polynomial $p(x)$ means that $p(x) = l(x)q(x)+r(x)$.

Comment: How did you calculate $Q(x)$ or it was just assumed that it will be $'0,-5'$ in the respective cases.

Comment: Consider $x^{60}-1$. This is $(x^6-1)(x^{54}+x^{48}+\cdots +1) = f(x)(x-1)(x^{54}+x^{48}+\cdots + 1)$. Similarly we can write the other terms on the right hand side. If you collect all those terms, take out $f(x)$, what remains is $Q(X)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Last question : how did you think of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{6}}$. Then $f(x) = (x-\omega)(x-\omega^2) \cdots (x-\omega^5)$. Since $f((\omega^i)^{12}) = 6$ for all $i = 1,2,\ldots,5$, it follows that $f(x^{12})-6$ is divisible by $x-\omega^i$. Hence $f(x^{12})-6$ is divisible by $f(x)$.